# Meaning and construction of “no way I could have …”

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms, word-order

> She turned up at the doorstep of my house in Cornwall. ***No
>   way could I have sent her away.*** No way, not me anyway.

My question is :
Is "No way could I have sent her away"  an inverted sentence? Why should it be inverted?  If it was stated by declarative sentence, should it be :"I could have sent her away no way" or "I could have here away in no way"? Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

1. the inversion is emphatic and old-fashioned -- the normal way to say this would be "There was no way that I could have sent her away."
2. I don't know how it is classified. It is a very standard way to indicate the time in which something happened.
3. the author is imagining the thoughts of whoever abandoned the dog. (The author does not know who abandoned the dog, or why.) She is imagining that this person abandoned the dog because they were about to have a baby, and did not have room for both.
4. this is the "around" sense of the word "about," not the sense of "relevant, related to." This is an old-fashioned sense of the word "about" and is mostly limited to writing and some fixed expressions like "around and about."
5. "happened to" is a standard phrase -- when something affects someone you say "something happened to him." Here the author is imagining the dog's previous owners doing something bad to the dog, and saying "I don't know what happened to her [at her old owner's house.]" The verb happen never takes the preposition on.
6. The sentence is indeed missing a subject; it's not a "complete sentence." Parse it like "the dog was always..."
7. No, that's a fine phrase.  Parse it like "I was very tired [and I was] very upset." Remember that a verb can take more than one direct object and does not need to be repeated.
8. yes, it means the same as "added a boy from somewhere behind her." I don't understand your complaint about syntax.